# Query using group by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with the query using group by month. This query returns `total_revenue` per month. but if month of year doesn't contain any data then `total_revnue` is increased unnecessarily.

```
SELECT COUNT(CT.cumTxnReportId),
   CT.cumTxnReportId,
   CT.ticketNum,
   DATE_FORMAT(CT.exitDateTimeUtc,'%m-%Y'),
   sum(netAmount) AS total_revenue,
   D.name,
   HOUR(CT.entranceDateTimeUtc) AS entryHour,
   HOUR(CT.exitDateTimeUtc) AS exitHour,
   CT.entranceDateTimeUtc,
   CT.exitDateTimeUtc,
   CT.netAmount AS netAmount,
   CT.grossAmount,
   CT.discountAmount,
   CT.rate,
   CT.txnType,
   CT.ticketType,
   CT.txnNum,
   CT.numDiscounts
FROM Parkloco.ParkingArea PA
JOIN IParcPro.Device D ON PA.id = D.parkingAreaId
JOIN Parkloco.RateCard RC ON PA.id = RC.parkingAreaId
JOIN IParcPro.CumTxn CT ON D.id = CT.deviceId
WHERE PA.uuid = '27d842c1-7057-11e6-a0eb-1245b0d35d23'
  AND (CT.txnType = 'Allowed'
       OR CT.txnType = 'Add'
       OR CT.txnType = 'Normal'
       OR CT.txnType = 'Offline'
       OR CT.txnType = 'Repay')
  AND ((CT.entranceDateTimeUtc >= '2016-08-01 00:00:00'
        AND CT.exitDateTimeUtc <= '2017-04-31 23:59:59'))
  AND (RC.state = 'active'
       OR RC.state = 'archived')
  AND RC.fromDateTimeUtc <= '2017-04-31 23:59:59'
  AND (RC.thruDateTimeUtc IS NULL
       OR RC.thruDateTimeUtc >= '2016-08-01 00:00:00')
  AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF (SECOND, CT.entranceDateTimeUtc, CT.exitDateTimeUtc) >= '0' * 60)
  AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF (SECOND, CT.entranceDateTimeUtc, CT.exitDateTimeUtc) < '1441' * 60)
  AND CT.numDiscounts=0
  AND CT.ticketNum !=0
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(CT.exitDateTimeUtc,'%m-%Y')
```

[image]

but when I am increasing the range month - at that point of time I am getting unneccessary increment in `total_revenue`

```
SELECT COUNT(CT.cumTxnReportId),
   CT.cumTxnReportId,
   CT.ticketNum,
   DATE_FORMAT(CT.exitDateTimeUtc,'%m-%Y'),
   sum(netAmount) AS total_revenue,
   D.name,
   HOUR(CT.entranceDateTimeUtc) AS entryHour,
   HOUR(CT.exitDateTimeUtc) AS exitHour,
   CT.entranceDateTimeUtc,
   CT.exitDateTimeUtc,
   CT.netAmount AS netAmount,
   CT.grossAmount,
   CT.discountAmount,
   CT.rate,
   CT.txnType,
   CT.ticketType,
   CT.txnNum,
   CT.numDiscounts
FROM Parkloco.ParkingArea PA
JOIN IParcPro.Device D ON PA.id = D.parkingAreaId
JOIN Parkloco.RateCard RC ON PA.id = RC.parkingAreaId
JOIN IParcPro.CumTxn CT ON D.id = CT.deviceId
WHERE PA.uuid = '27d842c1-7057-11e6-a0eb-1245b0d35d23'
  AND (CT.txnType = 'Allowed'
       OR CT.txnType = 'Add'
       OR CT.txnType = 'Normal'
       OR CT.txnType = 'Offline'
       OR CT.txnType = 'Repay')
  AND ((CT.entranceDateTimeUtc >= '2016-08-01 00:00:00'
        AND CT.exitDateTimeUtc <= '2017-07-31 23:59:59'))
  AND (RC.state = 'active'
       OR RC.state = 'archived')
  AND RC.fromDateTimeUtc <= '2017-07-31 23:59:59'
  AND (RC.thruDateTimeUtc IS NULL
       OR RC.thruDateTimeUtc >= '2016-08-01 00:00:00')
  AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF (SECOND, CT.entranceDateTimeUtc, CT.exitDateTimeUtc) >= '0' * 60)
  AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF (SECOND, CT.entranceDateTimeUtc, CT.exitDateTimeUtc) < '1441' * 60)
  AND CT.numDiscounts=0
  AND CT.ticketNum !=0
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(CT.exitDateTimeUtc,'%m-%Y')
```

output such as :

[image]
can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance if you could let me know.

Comment: Please try [formatting your SQL](https://sqlformat.org/)...

Comment: Its formatted now could you guys please have a look.

Comment: Incidentally, MySQL includes the IN() construct.

Comment: What table does `netAmount` come from? What is the meaning of the column `RC.fromDateTimeUtc`?

Answer (score 2):

Despite MySQL allow this weird `group by` rules, in my opinion, you should to avoid use it. I explain, usually, all `select clause` non aggregate fields should appear on `group by` clause:

```
select a,b,c, sum(z)
from t
group by a,b,c
```

vs

```
select a,b,c, sum(z)
from t
group by a   #<--- MySQL allow this!
```

Then, if `b` and `c` are not in group by, how MySQL figure up the right fields to be selected? [Like this on <5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html):

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

In my opinion, in **your query has no sense**: Look `entryHour` and `total_revenue`. One is for an entry the other one is for all month.

I guess you should to rethink the hole sql statement. Because the result of this one is incoherent.

Also, remember this is not 'code revision service'. Please, read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order your question also help other users.